# ソートがタイムアウトしてしまう

Tags: c

> 配列の 0 番⽬が “elephant”、1 番⽬が“giraffe”、2 番⽬が“crocodile”、3 番⽬が“panda”、4 番⽬が“chimpanzee” となるように宣⾔をし、ポインタ配列 sortP の中に ASCII コードで降順に並び替えて値を格納して、sortP の結果を表⽰させなさい。

という問題ですが、下記のように書いてtimeoutになってしまいます。
どこがわるいのでしょうか？sortの中身だとは思いますが…

```
#include <stdio.h>

char compare(char c1, char c2)
{
    return (c1 - c2);
}

void sort_rev(char **array)
{
    int i, j, k;
    char *temp;

    i = 0;
    while (i < 4)
    {
        j = 0;
        while (++j < 5)
        {
            k = 0;
            while (array[i][k] != '\0' && array[j][k] != '\0')
            {
                if  (compare(array[i][k], array[j][k]) == 0)
                {
                    k++;
                }
                else if (compare(array[i][k], array[j][k]) < 0)
                {
                    temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                }

            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return ;
}

int main(void){
    // Your code here!
    char *sortP[255] = {
        "elephant", "giraffe", "crocodile", "panda", "chimpanzee"
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("inside sortP before sorth: %s\n", *(sortP + i));
    }
    sort_rev(sortP);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("answer: %s\n", *(sortP + i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

本題とは無関係ですが、ソースコードのあちこちに `4` とか `5` といった即値が散りばめられているのはちょっと…と思うので(書き間違えると大変)、`char *` 型の配列 `sortP` の要素数を予め計算しておいて、`sort_rev` 関数に渡す様にするとよろしいのではないかと思います。参考までに実装例を挙げておきます。

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// swap two variables
#define swap(a, b) { __typeof__(a) temp = a; a = b; b = temp; }

// prototype declaration
void sort_rev(const char *array[], const int len);

// sort in reverse order
void sort_rev(const char *array[], const int len) {
  for(int i=0;i<(len-1);i++){
    for(int j=i+1,k=0;j<len;j++,k=0) {
      while(array[i][k] != '\0' && array[j][k] != '\0') {
        char diff = array[i][k] - array[j][k];
        if (diff == 0) { k++; continue; }
        if (diff < 0)  { swap(array[i], array[j]); }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return;
}

// main routine
int main() {
  const char *sortP[] = {
    "elephant", "giraffe", "crocodile", "panda", "chimpanzee"
  };
  const int l = sizeof(sortP)/sizeof(char *);

  for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
    printf("inside sortP before sort: %s\n", sortP[i]);
  }

  sort_rev(sortP, l);

  for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
    printf("answer: %s\n", sortP[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`array[0]`（`i`=0）が参照元の場合、`j`が1から4までループします。　　
あと、`array[1]`（`i`=1）を参照元にした後、`j`は1ではなく、2から4までループします。

```
    while (i < 4)
    {
        j = i;  // j = 0;  //　変更
        while (++j < 5)
```

---

文字列を比較する時、交換するか、しないかが決まったら、`k`のループをbreakします。

```
                else if (compare(array[i][k], array[j][k]) < 0)
                {
                    temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
　　　　　　　　　　　break;  //  追加
                }
                //  以下のelseを追加
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
```